# Как можно восстановить HDD компьютера?

Tags: windows, windows-7, железо, hdd

С недавних пор начались проблемы с компьютером. Поначалу частые прекращение работы (в последствии перезагрузка) программы проводник, затем все чаще появление синего экрана (критической ошибки). После переустановки системы проблемы начали проявляться зависанием ПК, да так, что отключались и клавиатура и мышь, и картинка замирала; бывало даже зависал в процессе включения/выключения. Погуглил проблему все сходится к тому что накрывается HDD. Протестировал программой Victoria 4.47, вот скрин из вкладки SMART:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и после теста:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем попробовал пройти тест с функцией Remap, вот что получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как еще можно восстановить его работоспособность? Конечно, в идеале желательно заменить его и заменить на SSD, но пока этого не произошло, желательно, чтобы он протянул еще некоторое время. Подскажите чем можно этого достичь? Возможно пройтись Defragger-om или это без толку?

Comment: Вы ему ничем не поможете. Сейчас pending секторов нет и это не плохо. Если начнут они появляться или расти переназначенные - менять и как можно быстрее. Дефраг и прочее лучше не запускать - это лишняя серьезная нагрузка на диск, она ему сейчас ни к чему

Comment: Да не похоже как-то на большие проблемы с диском. Да, старенький, поюзанный, но ничего критичного не видать. Попробуйте отключить его, загрузиться с какого-нить ремонтного LiveCD (скажем. от С.Стрельца) да погонять железо в стресс-тестах.

Comment: Можно попробовать MHDD и принудительный ремап, но количество "отключаемых" секторов ограничено и уже порядком использовано, поэтому на долго не поможет, лучше заменить как можно быстрее, а бекап нужных файлов на внешний носитель сделать уже сейчас

Comment: @rdorn К сожалению заменить пока возможности нет поэтому и хотел узнать чем можно продлить ему жизнь (чтобы он хотя бы не зависал и не перезагружался когда ему вздумается) работать невозможно. Ну а на счет бекапа - я давно все выгрузил на облако чтобы чего не случилось))

Comment: Можете сделать загрузку с флешки или LifeCD, а на диске оставить только рабочие данные. Хотя тут конечно зависит от того, что вы называете "работать", оно у всех разное.

Comment: @Akina, КАК не похоже на проблемы с диском? Почти 19к часов наработки и 1813 переназначенных секторов? ЭТО И ЕСТЬ проблемы.

Comment: @donRumata Это не проблемы, это текущее состояние, которое да. не лучшее, но и не из рук вон... 19к часов = 2 года непрерывной работы для диска - ещё не старость. 1к8 переназначенных секторов - тоже не так уж и много, у меня есть диски с 3-4к ремапов, но их состояние стабильное, и я за них вообще не переживаю. Вот если это количество постоянно растёт - тогда другой разговор, но как раз динамики-то мы и не видим.

Comment: @Akina, не согласен. Если на таких винтах хранится некритичная информация и они лежат на книжной полке, то конечно пофиг. А для ОС и нормальной работы - я бы такие диски не ставил (и собсно не ставлю).

Answer (score 1):

Дам обратный совет: 
 - гонять стресс тестами можно если вы решаете судьбу винта - оставить или выбросить
 - стресс тесты покажут конечно проблемные места но вместе с тем они его могут убить окончательно 
- если вам дорога информация не советую экспериментировать со стресс тестами особенно не ориентируясь в настройках тестов

Comment: ППКС. Надо срочно делать бэкапы важных файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Первое действие - немедленный бэкап данных. С большой вероятностью там уже полно битых файлов, и каждая минута промедления их число увеличивает.

Второе действие - замена диска. Этот диск в мусорное ведро без вариантов. Продлить ему жизнь невозможно, можно только ее укоротить.

Если на диске ничего ценного нет, то можете конечно и подождать пока он совсем не помрет.